# Close vim 8.1+ terminal buffer without unloading

Tags: terminal-buffer, vim8

I'm looking to be able to close a terminal buffer without unloading it, as I would with a normal buffer and either `hidden` or `bufhidden=hide` set. It appears, though, that said options are ignored for terminal buffers. Note that I'm using vim 8.2.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
vim -u NONE
:set hidden
:vnew regular_buffer
:close
:ls
```

buffers:

```
:ls
  1 %a   "[No Name]"                    line 1
  2 #h   "regular_buffer"               line 0
```

next, create a terminal buffer:

```
:call term_start('ls', {'term_name': 'terminal_test'})
:ls
```

and the new buffer list:

```
:ls
  1 #a   "[No Name]"                    line 1
  2  h   "regular_buffer"               line 0
  3 %aF  "terminal_test [finished]"     line 1
```

now, close the terminal buffer:

```
:close
```

and again show the buffer list:

```
:ls
  1 %a   "[No Name]"                    line 1
  2 #h   "regular_buffer"               line 0
```

Trying to reopen the buffer (`:b3`) confirms it no longer exists. How can I keep my terminal buffer loaded (and in the buffer list) after closing its window?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal buffer is special:

> When the job has finished and no changes were made to the buffer: closing the
> window will wipe out the buffer.

Change buffer type will stop this.

### Manual

After job finished, clear buffer type:

```
setlocal buftype=
```

This also works:

```
setlocal modifiable
" make any change, the 1st change will convert terminal buffer to be a normal buffer.
```

See doc after `:h E948` for detail.

### Auto

Pass this options to `term_start`:

```
{ 'term_finish' : 'open',  'term_opencmd' : 'call setbufvar(%d, "&buftype", "")' }
```

It will clear buffer type when the job is finished, the `%d` will be replaced with terminal buffer number.

See `:h term_start` for detail.